# Probability of random variable for an unfair coin.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose, a fair coin in tossed 3 times, and we count the number of heads.

```
 HHH = 3 heads = 1/8
 HHT = 2 heads = 1/8
 HTH = 2 heads = 1/8
 HTT = 1 heads = 1/8
 THH = 2 heads = 1/8
 THT = 1 heads = 1/8
 TTH = 1 heads = 1/8
 TTT = 0 heads = 1/8
```

So,

```
 Heads       Probability
   0             1/8
   1             3/8
   2             3/8
   3             1/8
```

So,

$P(X=1) = 3/8$

How would this be different in case of $P(head) = 3/4$.

My calculation is, in case of $P(head) = 3/4$, $P(tail) = 1/4$.

So, if there are 1 head and 2 tails, we have:

$P(X=1) = 3*(3/4)*(1/4)*(1/4) = 9/64$

Am I correct?

Is there any other way to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would this be different in the case of $P(head)=\tfrac 34$.

Or indeed $P(head)=p$

```
HHH = 3 heads = 27/64      = p^3
HHT = 2 heads =  9/64      = (1-p)p^2
HTH = 2 heads =  9/64      = (1-p)p^2
HTT = 1 heads =  3/64      = (1-p)^2 p
THH = 2 heads =  9/64      = (1-p)p^2
THT = 1 heads =  3/64      = (1-p)^2 p
TTH = 1 heads =  3/64      = (1-p)^2 p
TTT = 0 heads =  1/64      = (1-p)^3
```

So,

```
Heads       Probability
  0             1/64      = (1-p)^3
  1             9/64      = 3 (1-p)^2 p
  2            27/64      = 3 (1-p) p^2
  3            27/64      = p^3
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is indeed correct for a biased coin. In general, if we have a biased coin with probability $p$ of heads, and we flip it $n$ times, the probability of getting exactly $k$ heads is ${n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. See here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Is there any other way to calculate this?

Comment: @user366312 It is unlikely that there is any better way to calculate this; that formula is exact and does not have any simpler form.

Comment: @auscrypt You probably meant: "Yes, that is indeed correct for an *unbiased* coin..."

Comment: I think there's a typo, the last exponent is n - k , is it not?